# Unable to resolve Robotium Dependency Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, robotium, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to use Robotium for writing test cases in Android Studio and I am having a hard time configuring things.

Following is my build.gradle inside the app.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')

    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'

}
```

When I clean the project, I get the following error:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':NativeSDK'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':NativeSDK:_debugTestCompile'.
>   Could not find com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1.
>        Required by:
>            InAppSDK:NativeSDK:unspecified
>   Could not find junit:junit:4.11.
>        Required by:
>            InAppSDK:NativeSDK:unspecified

Any help on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you include the contents of your top-level build file?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that in your top level build.gradle you have the repositories{mavenCentral()} or repositories{jcenter()} in your buildscript{}

When you provide the reference to an artifact in mavenCentral() or jCenter() you need to sync the project after disabling the offline work at least once under studio>preference>gradle>offline work.

Having this will solve the issue. Its just the local cache of the studio has not been updated as per my understanding. You can check the available library version in mavenCentral() or jcenter() in your case its 5.1 for robotium. (better to use 5.2.1 which is the newest as of today)

make sure that you don't have the robotium jar in your libs folder as you are compiling libs file tree. If you have the jar file when compiling it will throw a UNEXPECTED_TOP_LEVEL exception.